# Timing Attack C - Transformed from java

Tags: java, c, transformation, benchmarking

My first post. :)

In the last weeks I wrote a Timing Attack Implementation in java for the method:

```
static char[] a = new char[] { 's', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', '1' };

static boolean passwordCompare(char[] a, char[] b){
    int i;
    if (a.length != b.length)
        return false;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length && a[i] == b[i]; i++);
         return i == a.length;}
```

Everything went as expected. But then I wanted to write the same Attack in C, because that's the programming language I'm trying to learn at the moment and nothing goes right.

I would appreciate every little aid. :)

password_compare.o is the lib, where the method password_compare(const char *password)
and the secret password lies.

Cheers!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "password_compare.o"

/* foreach macro for using a string as a collection of char */
#define foreach( ptrvar, strvar ) char* ptrvar; for( ptrvar=strvar ; 
        (*ptrvar) != '\0' ; *ptrvar++)


int main(void)
{
  // variables
   int counter;
   char[] test;
   long begin, end, begin2, end2;
   long duration;
   long duration2;
   long store = 0;
   char [] storechar;
   char[] tester;
   char [] storechar2;

 // Try to find out the length from the password. 
 // Longest time = password.length.
   for(int i=0; i<=10; ++i)
   {
      test = new char[i];
        for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
         {
          test[j]=a;
         }

      const char [] fixtest = test;
      time_t start = time(0);
        for (int k=0; k<1000000000;k++)
         {

         password_compare(fixtest);
         }

      time_t end = time(0);
      duration = end-start;
        if(duration > store)
          {
            store = duration;
            storechar = test;
            counter = i; 
          }


        printf("Duration (" + i + ") = " + duration);
  }

  printf("The right length is :" + storechar.length);

  int len=sizeof(storechar)/sizeof(int);
  storechar2 = new char[len];
  tester = new char[counter];

  // Iterate through each position from the password array.
  for (int h=0; h<len; h++)
     {
        long store2 = 0;

        // Generate an char[] as String 
        // with all possible characters.
        char* s1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabc
                    defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

        // Check for each character from s1 ... 

         foreach(p1, s1)
          {
             tester[h] = *p1;
             const char [] fixtester = tester;

             // Check for each p1 in s1 at Position h the time. 
             //The largest value will be saved at Pos h.  

              if (h < (len-1))
              {

                  time_t start2  = time();
              for ( int k = 0; k<1000000000;k++)
              {
                 password_compare(fixtester);
              }
              for ( int p = 0; p<1000000000;p++)
              {
                 password_compare(fixtester);
              }

              time_t end2 = time();
              duration2 = end2-begin2;
                if ( duration2 > store2)
                 {
                    store2 = duration2;
                storechar2[h] = *p1;
                 }
             printf("Duration (" + *p1 + ") = " + duration2);
              }

            // else if h == password.length, then try 
            // every character at the last position.

            else if (password_compare(fixtester) == true)
                {
                     storechar2[h] = *p1;
                     printf("Character at Pos " + (h + 1) + ": ")
                     printf("storechar2[%d]: %d\n",h,storechar2[h]);
                     printf("The Password is: ");

                         for(int b = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) 
                            {printf("%d ",storechar2[b]);}


                     exit(0);

               }
          }

       printf("Character at Pos " + (h + 1) + ": ");
       printf("storechar2[%d]: %d\n",h,storechar2[h]);
       tester[h] = storechar2[h];
    }

      // The Password was guessed wrong!
       printf("Failed");
       exit(0);
       return(0);
```

}

Comment: it would help if you format the code. and split it to functions.

Comment: BTW, `#include "password_compare.o"` is *wrong*. you should pass it to the compiler (linker, actually), not add an `#include` for it.

Comment: I didn't realize that C had a `foreach` loop...That, and your Java loop is just wonky.  You're comparing Strings with `==`, and if it ever *enters* the loop, it'll immediately return.  You want a different construct for that.

Comment: The Java loop is fine. There are no strings, and the return is after the loop body.

Comment: If i now try to compile/run it with :  gcc -o Attack2 Attack2.c password_compare            ( I use MinGW )
I get plenty of erros for example:
I keep getting this error, "stray '\1' in program", "stray '\2' in program" or insteand with 20,33,7,10,220,1,34 like 150 times.
Furthermore  Error: expected »=«, »,«, »;«, »asm« or »__attribute__« before »>« token.  :/

Comment: Anyone an idea for these problems?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple syntax errors, for example:

```
#define foreach( ptrvar, strvar ) char* ptrvar; for( ptrvar=strvar ; 
    (*ptrvar) != '\0' ; *ptrvar++)
```

Only the first line is part of the macro. To use multiple lines, add a backslash at the end.

```
char [] storechar;
storechar2 = new char[len];
```

This array syntax is from Java. Check how to define arrays in C.

```
#include "password_compare.o"
```

This fills the file with junk. You want to include header files, not object files.

If you can't fix the problems, then start with a new file and add one thing at a time. Check that it compiles before adding anything else. If there's an error, note the exact message and the lines that caused it.